# Intersection of curves in non-singular projective algebraic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Bezout thereom that says that two irreducible algebraic curves $C$ and $D$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ intersect at $nm$ points (counted with multiplicity), where $n$ and $m$ are the degrees of $C$ and $D$, respectively. So in this case we know that $C\cdot D=nm$ is finite.

The question is, if I change $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ by any other non-singular projective algebraic surface $X$, may I find two irreducible algebraic curves $C,D \subset X$ such that $C \cdot D=\infty$? If yes, what can we say about $X$, $C$ and $D$?

Comment: On any smooth projective surface, $C\cdot D$ is defined in such a way that it's an integer. So no, $C\cdot D$ won't be $\infty$. Of course $C\cap D$ might be an infinite set, even in the plane.

Comment: @DonuArapura As far as I know $C \cdot D \geq \#(C \cap D)$ (since it is the sume of the intersection multiplicities at points of $C \cap D$), so I do not understand how $ \# (C \cap D)$ can be inifnite but not $C\cdot D$. On the other hand, when you say that "$C \cap D$ might be infinite, even in the plane", I guess you make reference to the projective plane, but here we have $\# (C \cap D) \leq nm$. You're answer doesn't convince me, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I think Donu means that $C\cap C$ will be infinite. However, $C\cdot C$ wont be.

Comment: The integer $C\cdot D$ is never infinite. However, $C\cdot D \ge \#(C\cap D)$ only when $C$ and $D$ have no component in common. So your first sentence is not correct, as Donu Arapura says.

Comment: Some potential confusion of the OP may be that it is assumed in the question that $C$ and $D$ are irreducible, but not necessarily in the comments. But even in this case $C \cdot D$ is a well-defined integer, even when $C = D$. I would recommend that the OP read Chapter V.1 of Hartshorne (see in particular Theorem 1.1).

Comment: @BMS Other people have caught my meaning. I second Daniel suggestion of reading that section of Hartshorne. Let me also observe the following which might help you. Lemma: if $C$ and $D$ are *distinct* irreducible curves on a variety $X$, then $C\cap D$ is finite. Proof: The intersection is a proper Zariski closed subset of $C$.

Comment: See Reid: Chapters on Algebraic Surfaces, arXiv:alg-geom/9602006, Chapter A for the basic statements (without proof) and lots of worked-out examples.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably more suitable for MSE. However, since it is still open and it has (currently) three upvotes, let me shortly answer it. Of course, my answer is just an extended version of the comments above, and everything I will say can be found in the classical literature on the subject, such as Beauville, Hartshorne, Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven, Griffiths-Harris, etc.

The intersection pairing $(C, D)$ on the Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}(X)  \simeq H^1(X, \, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$ of a a smooth, complex projective surface $X$ is induced by the intersection pairing in $H^2(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$, in the sense that $$(C, \, D)=c_1(C) \cup c_1(D) \in H^4(X, \, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z},$$ where $c_1 \colon \operatorname{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ is the first Chern class map, seen as the connecting homomorphism arising from the exponential sequence $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to  \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X^* \to 0.$$

In particular, the intersection number $(C, \, D)$ is *always* a (possibly negative) integer and it *cannot* be infinite.

When $C$, $D$ are holomorphic curves with no component in common then, by the Poincaré duality $H^4(X, \, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq H_0(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$, we are really counting the intersection points of $C$ and $D$ (with multiplicity); in fact, the natural orientation given by the complex structure tells us that each intersection point $p \in C \cap D$ must be counted with *positive* sign.

It follows that, if $(C, \, D)$ is negative, then the two curves $C$, $D$ must have a component in common; this means in particular that the *set* $C \cap D$ is infinite (but $(C, \, D)$ is not!).

As a typical example, consider the exceptional divisor $E$ of a smooth blow-up: then $E^2=-1$, even if $E \cap E =E$ is an infinite set. In fact, in general, the self-intersection number $(C, \, C)$ can be interpreted as the degree of the normal bundle $N_{C/X} \simeq \mathcal{O}_C(C)$ of $C$ in $X$.